# Syntx error near unexpected token '}'

Tags: bash, shell-script

i am trying to write a function but I am getting Syntax error. Below is my function:

```
checkNoOfParameter () {
    if [[ ${1} -eq ${2} ]]
    then
        job_Status = $true
    else
        job_Status = $false
        echo "Please provide all \"${2}\"  arguments with single space separation"
        readArgumentsFromUser ${2}
}
```

and I am calling the function like this:

```
    readArgumentsFromUser () {
      read -a input
      checkNoOfParameter ${#input[*]} ${1}
    }

    readArgumentsFromUser 3
```

Comment: Should I assume that your actual error is "syntax error near unexpected token `}'", or is this code incomplete?

Comment: Yes it is, Updating question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `fi` to end the if statement before the `}` closes the function.

You also have spaces in your assignments that shouldn't be there, so you will subsequently get errors "job_Status: command not found"; remove the spaces on both sides of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a 'fi':

```
checkNoOfParameter () {
    if [[ ${1} -eq ${2} ]]
    then
        job_Status = $true
    else
        job_Status = $false
        echo "Please provide all \"${2}\"  arguments with single space separation"
        readArgumentsFromUser ${2}
    fi
}
```

Also, you don't use '-eg' inside '[[ ... ]]'

Check out this tool to solve this kind of problem: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I am banging my head now. Thanks Thanks a lot

Comment: It’s looks to me that `-eq` are within the double brackets in his example. Also, the variable assignments are wrong. There shouldn’t be any white space around the equal signs (=).